# Swift JSOn Decoding Error: Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead

Tags: json, swift

I have the following problem.
I send a request to FatSecret API to get details of a food.
If I decode a generic food it works, but if I get a branded food it doesn't work.

My struct looks like:

```
struct fatsecretFood : Decodable {
let food : Food

struct Food : Decodable {
    let brand_name: String?
    let food_id: String?
    let food_name: String?
    let food_type: String?
    let food_url: String?

    let servings : Servings

    struct Servings : Decodable {
        let serving : [Serving]

        struct Serving : Decodable {
            let serving_id: String?
            let serving_description: String?
            let serving_url: String?
            let metric_serving_amount: String?
            let metric_serving_unit: String?
            let number_of_units: String?
            let measurement_description: String?

            let calories: String?
            let carbohydrate: String?
            let protein: String?
            let fat: String?
            let saturated_fat: String?
            let polyunsaturated_fat: String?
            let monounsaturated_fat: String?
            let trans_fat: String?
            let cholesterol: String?
            let sodium: String?
            let potassium: String?
            let fiber: String?
            let sugar: String?
            let vitamin_a: String?
            let vitamin_c: String?
            let calcium: String?
            let iron: String?
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code line with the error:

```
let data = Data(requestResponse.utf8)
    var foodDetails: fatsecretFood!
    var errors: fatsecretError!
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(fatsecretFood.self, from: data)
        foodDetails = result
    } catch { print(error) }
return foodDetails!
```

At that return I get the error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "food", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "servings", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "serving", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

The JSON of the example generic food (works) looks like:

```
{
  "food": {
  "food_id": "38884",
  "food_name": "Chocolate Chip Cookies (Soft Type)",
  "food_type": "Generic",
  "food_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/chocolate-chip-cookies-(soft-type)",
  "servings": {
     "serving": [
        {
           "calcium": "0",
           "calories": "130",
           "carbohydrate": "16.75",
           "cholesterol": "0",
           "fat": "6.89",
           "fiber": "0.9",
           "iron": "4",
           "measurement_description": "oz",
           "metric_serving_amount": "28.350",
           "metric_serving_unit": "g",
           "monounsaturated_fat": "3.695",
           "number_of_units": "1.000",
           "polyunsaturated_fat": "0.992",
           "potassium": "26",
           "protein": "0.99",
           "saturated_fat": "2.101",
           "serving_description": "1 oz",
           "serving_id": "38785",
           "serving_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/chocolate-chip-cookies-(soft-type)?portionid=38785&portionamount=1.000",
           "sodium": "92",
           "vitamin_a": "0",
           "vitamin_c": "0"
        },
        {
           "calcium": "0",
           "calories": "69",
           "carbohydrate": "8.86",
           "cholesterol": "0",
           "fat": "3.64",
           "fiber": "0.5",
           "iron": "2",
           "measurement_description": "cookie",
           "metric_serving_amount": "15.000",
           "metric_serving_unit": "g",
           "monounsaturated_fat": "1.955",
           "number_of_units": "1.000",
           "polyunsaturated_fat": "0.525",
           "potassium": "14",
           "protein": "0.52",
           "saturated_fat": "1.112",
           "serving_description": "1 cookie",
           "serving_id": "38786",
           "serving_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/chocolate-chip-cookies-(soft-type)?portionid=38786&portionamount=1.000",
           "sodium": "49",
           "vitamin_a": "0",
           "vitamin_c": "0"
        },
        {
           "calcium": "2",
           "calories": "458",
           "carbohydrate": "59.10",
           "cholesterol": "0",
           "fat": "24.30",
           "fiber": "3.2",
           "iron": "13",
           "measurement_description": "g",
           "metric_serving_amount": "100.000",
           "metric_serving_unit": "g",
           "monounsaturated_fat": "13.034",
           "number_of_units": "100.000",
           "polyunsaturated_fat": "3.500",
           "potassium": "93",
           "protein": "3.50",
           "saturated_fat": "7.411",
           "serving_description": "100 g",
           "serving_id": "61615",
           "serving_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/chocolate-chip-cookies-(soft-type)?portionid=61615&portionamount=100.000",
           "sodium": "326",
           "vitamin_a": "0",
           "vitamin_c": "0"
        }
     ]
  }
}
}
```

The JSON of the example branded food (doesn't work) looks like:

```
{
 "food": {
   "brand_name": "Pepperidge Farm",
  "food_id": "61348",
  "food_name": "Soft Baked Sugar Cookies",
  "food_type": "Brand",
  "food_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/pepperidge-farm/soft-baked-sugar-cookies",
  "servings": {
     "serving": {
        "calcium": "0",
        "calories": "140",
        "carbohydrate": "22",
        "cholesterol": "10",
        "fat": "5",
        "fiber": "0",
        "iron": "4",
        "measurement_description": "serving",
        "metric_serving_amount": "31.000",
        "metric_serving_unit": "g",
        "monounsaturated_fat": "1.5",
        "number_of_units": "1.000",
        "polyunsaturated_fat": "0.5",
        "protein": "2",
        "saturated_fat": "2.5",
        "serving_description": "1 cookie",
        "serving_id": "103910",
        "serving_url": "https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/pepperidge-farm/soft-baked-sugar-cookies",
        "sodium": "90",
        "sugar": "11",
        "trans_fat": "0",
        "vitamin_a": "0",
        "vitamin_c": "0"
     }
  }
}
}
```

I don't find the error. Can someone help me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn to understand the error message, it's very easy to read

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "food", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "servings", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "serving", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

- `typeMismatch` means you declared a wrong type (`Swift.Array<Any>`).
- The `codingPath` array represents the key path to the affected location `food/servings/serving`.
- The *Expected* part of the `debugDescription` describes your mistake (array) the *found* part describes the actual type (dictionary which is a struct in terms of `Codable`).

---

To be able to decode both array and dictionary types you have to add a custom initializer. The final type of `serving` is always an array.

```
struct Servings : Decodable {
    let serving : [Serving]
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case serving }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            let servingDictionary = try container.decode(Serving.self, forKey: .serving)
            serving = [servingDictionary]
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            serving = try container.decode([Serving].self, forKey: .serving)
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Name structs always with a starting uppercase letter.
- Don't use *snake_cased* variable names. Add `.convertFromSnakeCase` strategy and declare *camelCased* names.
- Don't declare carelessly everything as optional. It seems that at least the `Serving` object sends always **all** keys.

Answer (score 1):

`serving` is not an `Array` as you suggest in your decoder. It is another `dictionary` as shown in the JSON file. Try to replace your code line:

```
let serving : [Serving] // before

let serving : Serving // after
```

If `serving` was an array in the JSON, it would look something like this:

```
"serving":[
    {  
        "calcium":"8",
        // ...
    },
    {
        "calcium":"10",
        // ...
    }
]
```

Comment: But there can be more than one Serving

Comment: Can you give an example of a json file with multiple servings?

Comment: I'm on the way, give me a second

Comment: @moxmlb Neither of your examples contains an array so this looks like the right answer

Comment: I added a sample with multiple serving

Comment: If I change the code like the answer, I get the error at the first JSON sample and not at the second, the second works now but the first not

Comment: @moxmlb Is that from the same api call or are you using different calls?

Comment: How you mean different calls? I cal the API with the same method

Comment: @moxmlb can you double check that the JSON data from the first example is truly what you posted above? It should also result in an error since the JSON represents the same data structure as in the second example...

Comment: Yes both JSON data are right. At the second I get the error, at first not. And If I change the code like you posted, I get at the first an error and at the second not

Comment: Which API call are you using exactly? I checked https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiref2&method=food.get and could not find it describing an array for serving.

Comment: I use food.get in the call as method. In servings can be more then one serving, see the third example

Comment: @moxmlb It's clear from the documentation that there is no array returned, if you still get an array in the reply I suggest you contact fastsecret.com

Comment: I updated the first example, please check, there I get a return of serving []

Comment: It looks like that If there ist one serving it returns no serving [ ] but a serving { }. At more serving it returns like example 1. For only one example 2

Comment: @moxmlb I guess so, imho that is bad API design by FastSecret. If there is only one serving they should return an array with exactly the one serving and not return a different json data type construct.

Comment: Yes its really bad